# jquery - truncate text in paragraph

Tags: jquery

So I have created div (it has set height and overflow) with two paragraphs and "read more" link. The second paragraph is hidden.

```
<div class="text">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam iusto, voluptatum dolorem maiores ratione accusamus modi, sit. Velit nobis quod praesentium quaerat. Sunt mollitia odit asperiores numquam, debitis facere. Nulla.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam iusto, voluptatum dolorem maiores ratione accusamus modi, sit. Velit nobis quod praesentium quaerat. Sunt mollitia odit asperiores numquam, debitis facere. Nulla.</p>
</div>
<div><a class="more" href="#">read more</a></div>
```

Using this script when I click on "read more" it shows the second paragraph.

```
$('.more').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.text').css({
       'height': 'auto'
    });
    $('.more').hide();
});
```

What I need to do now is to truncate the text in first paragraph to 50 chars and replace the rest with: "...read more". Again when you click on "read more" it should reveal all the text from both paragraphs. How would I do that?

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926435/jquery-read-more-toggle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Read More Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926435/jquery-read-more-toggle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var firstPara = $('.text p:first').text(); /* Get text in first paragraph */

    $('.text p:first').html(firstPara.substring(0,50)+' <a class="more" href="#">read more</a>');  /* Replace first paragraph text with first 50 characters  */

    $('.text p:last').append(firstPara.substring(50));  /* Append remaining text to Second paragraph   */

$('body').on('click','a.more',function(){
/*enable second para on more click*/
   $('.text p:last').show()
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for wanting to help! It would be excellent for you to comment your code or else provide some explanation of what this solution does - code-only answers are not very useful